# Unable to access relatedTarget using the event object in FireFox

Tags: jquery, events, codemirror

I am using `CodeMirror` editor in for YAML.
I have the below code.

```
$('#' + element.id).ready(function() {
  editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(element.id), Options);
  editor.setValue(self.test());
  editor.on('blur', function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.relatedTarget;
    var isAddDialogButtonClicked = false;
    if (clickedElement !== null) {
      isAddDialogButtonClicked = clickedElement && clickedElement.parentElement &&
        clickedElement.parentElement.id === bindingContextData.addDialogButtonId();
    }
  });
});
```

The `event.relatedTarget` is not working in FireFox. It works fine in Chrome.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeMirror onBlur event handler takes 'event' as second param.
**editor.on('blur', function(instance, event) {});**

Answer (score 0):

You can access the native DOM from jQuerys event using `event.originalEvent`, maybe you can find the relatedTarget in there? Also according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) the `event.relatedTarget` is only available for certain events. Copied from MDN 2018-12-07:

```
The MouseEvent.relatedTarget read-only property is the secondary target for the mouse event, if there is one.

Event name     target                                           relatedTarget
focusin        The EventTarget receiving focus                  The EventTarget losing focus
focusout       The EventTarget losing focus                     The EventTarget receiving focus
mouseenter     The EventTarget the pointing device entered to   The EventTarget the pointing device exited from
mouseleave     The EventTarget the pointing device exited from  The EventTarget the pointing device entered to
mouseout       The EventTarget the pointing device exited from  The EventTarget the pointing device entered to
mouseover      The EventTarget the pointing device entered to   The EventTarget the pointing device exited from
dragenter      The EventTarget the pointing device entered to   The EventTarget the pointing device exited from
dragexit       The EventTarget the pointing device exited from  The EventTarget the pointing device entered to

For events with no secondary target, relatedTarget returns null.
```

It doesn't have `blur` in there, but I'm pretty sure `blur` is just an alias for `focusout`.

Alternatively, hook directly into vanilla javascript, jQuery is overrated:

```
editor[0].addEventListener( 'blur', function( event ){
    // whatevs
}
```

(the `editor[0]` accesses the native DOM element from the returned jQuery object)

Otherwise, refactor?

Comment: I was able to solve this. CodeMirror onBlur event handler takes event as second param                            editor.on('blur', function(instance, event) {});

Comment: Cool can you post that as an answer and give it the big green tick?